# Suggestions for a Computer Security presentation?

Tags: security, presentations

We have to do a presentation for my computer security class. It can be a demo or just a normal PowerPoint presentation. One of the kids in class is doing on cracking WEP. He is going to demonstrate to the class how to.

I'm not sure what to do it on. What would be an interesting topic to demo? I was thinking social engineering. However my professor says, "as long as you include a hands on component."

How would you even do that with social engineering?

Answer (score 2):

Make a website that looks legit asking for their credentials?

Comment: yeah, that's called SET.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-EZ0xfNUUr8